# How do I set the AccessControlContext in Java?

Tags: java, security, unit-testing, mocking

I'm fairly new to Java security stuff and I'm having a hard time figuring out how to google the right answer to this.

I have a line of code that reads `AccessController.getContext()`.

I want to run a test where I mock the result of this.  Unfortunately, I have no idea what I'm doing.

How do I set the `AccessControlContext` returned by `AccessController.getContext()`?

**Update**

Just to clarify, I know how to mock interfaces.  AccessController is a Java security feature.  I'm having trouble finding out how to set my own context so that when a method calls `AccessController.getContext()` it returns a AccessControlContext of my choosing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, I have this figured out.  Basically what I was trying to do was this:

```
Subject subject = Subject.getSubject(AccessController.getContext());
```

In order to create an `AccessControlContext` that contains a `Subject`, you have to call the method that attempts to obtain the subject like so:

```
Subject subject = new Subject();  //Set Principles here
Subject.doAs(subject, new PrivilegedAction<Void>()
{
    public Void run()
    {
        Foo.methodThatCaresAboutSubject();
    }
});
```